# How to execute jsonp response? Or how to make a string to a function call?

Tags: node.js, jsonp, exec

Following scenario:

- I use Node.js to connect to an API.
- I fire a request and get a jsonp response back.

This response look like:

```
processResponse({"LoginResponse":{"@token":"x"}})
```

That's it. Just that line: A string/object/text.

I have also a function `processResponse()`

```
processResponse(data){
   console.log(data);
};
```

My Question: How to get that response executed, since it is just an object. I wish to 'parse' a string to a function call.

```
  client.methods.loginRequest(loginArgs, function(data,response){
      //response body as js object
      console.log(data);
      // processResponse({"LoginResponse":{"@token":"x"}})

      // now I wish to execute it.
      data;        // this doesn't work
      data.exec(); // this doesn't work
      ?            // what else
  });

  function processResponse(data){
      console.log(data);
  };
```

I hope there is a way?

Comment: technically, you could do `eval(data)` to execute the response as a javascript statement, but a proper JSONP call shouldn't have to work that way and using `eval()` this way on unvetted data from a server has security risks.  A proper JSONP call should result in you receiving a javascript object which you can then pass to whatever function call you want.  You should be asking your server for data, not for a statement of javascript that you will execute.

Comment: Thank you, that's the keyword that I searched for. And yes, I absolutely agree with you. This work around is not the way to do so in production. I think more on some cases in sandbox. Performance measurements for different response routines for example.